# Check if array contains element and give output

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
tickets = Array.new(5) {rand(10)+1}
```

How can I make a ruby code, that checks if any `tickets` equals, for example 5. I want output something like

```
=> "Ticket #5 wins!"
```

So - if `tickets` generate `1, 5, 4, 2, 3` and my rule is it to equal 5, it outputs

```
=> "Ticket #5 wins!"
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the code to do?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."

Comment: @screenmutt - lets say that this code generates list of _bought_ 'tickets'. I should have the output with showing the winning ticket, only when it equals the winning number. In my example it is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if an array includes an element and print the result.

```
winner = 5
puts "Ticket ##{winner} wins!" if tickets.include? winner
```

Comment: The thing is - there is a chance that none of the numbers win. Winning numbers are generated elsewhere. 

So, technically output should appear only when any of the numbers from this generated list equals the other generated number.

Comment: That is what this code does. `if` the tickets `include` the winner, it `puts` the winner.